# How do I resolve resharper XAML error 'cannot resolve symbol' with XML data source?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resharper

I'm showing information from an XML file in a grid. This code works just fine and everything is displayed correctly. Resharper XAML analyzer complains:

*DataTemplate.DataType Cannot resolve symbol 'component'.*

Is there a way to tell Resharper that this is XML data and everything is ok?

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.DataContext>
     <XmlDataProvider Source="/data.xml" XPath="/component-data/component"/>
  </Grid.DataContext>
  <Grid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="component">
      <Border>
        <StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=./name}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=./rank}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=./serial}"/>
        </StackPanel>
      </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
  </ScrollViewer>
</Grid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we can supress/ignore the resharper errors. To do that:

1. List item find code issues in the file
2. select that perticular issue 'DataTemplate.DataType Cannot resolve symbol 'component'' from Inspection results bar.
3. choose 'choose ReSharper | Windows | Solution Errors'
4. You will be able to see small window 'Errors/Warnings in Solution '
5. select the issue and select ignore error.